# How to control sequence of Kafka Messages sent Asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, apache-kafka

I have developed a `Kafka version : 0.9.0.1` application.

One very important aspect of this application is that messages need to be consumed in the correct sequence. This is because I am propagating Database rows between two databases. This means I need to ensure all records within each Unit Of Work are sent as well as UOW-Insert arriving before UOW-Update.

If I use asynchronous message production, how can I guarantee the messages are consumed in the correct sequence?

I will employ `Kafka Producer` send with `Callback` to be notified whether or not each message was successfuly sent.

I will have `acks=all`, `retries=0`, `batch.size=16384` and my Kafka topics have a single partition.

My consumer can cope with duplicate messages, e.g. in the case of retries being necessary, however consumers cannot cope with messages out of sequence.

My retry approach will be to Fail Fast, e.g. as soon as a messages fails to send I report the records Log Record Sequence Number (LRSN) or Relative Byte Address (RBA) and stop sending any messages.

Then reset the source database logs to the reported LRSN or RBA and restart my message production.

for example I send messages

```
Message               UOW
M1                    uow-0000 
M2                    uow-0000 
M3                    uow-0000 
M4                    uow-0001 
M5                    uow-0001 
M6                    uow-0001 
M7                    uow-0001 
M8                    uow-0002
```

When message M5 failed to send successfully, I would stop sending anymore messages. However I have an issue that the consumer will have received messages M1, M2, M3, M4, M6, M7, & M8.

To recover this situation I will reset my source database log reader to the reported LRSN or RBA of M5 and start resending messages from that point.

Now the consumer receives

```
Message               UOW                    Duplicate
M5                    uow-0001                  No
M6                    uow-0001                  Yes
M7                    uow-0001                  Yes
M8                    uow-0002                  Yes
```

With this approach I get the speed of Asynchronous messaging and "hopefully" all messages consumed in the desired sequence.

Comment: You will need to switch to synchronous message writes.